# How to add a standard validation in the base class in Pysys

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a number of unit tests that extends a base class.

I want to add a validate condition to all testcases.  I know I can do in each test

```
def validate(self):
    # The base validation 
    BaseTest.validate(self)

    # This test validation 
    self.assertGrep(file='correlator.log', exprList='TEST PASSED')
```

Is there a way I can do this only by modifying the base class and without having to modify all testcases?

Or is it something that needs to be done in a Runner extension?

Comment: advice: try to use super(SubClass, self).validate() instead of BaseTest.validate(self)

Comment: Given that you're already calling the base class `validate` implementation, why not put the extra test in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of the pysys test framework which this question is based on, there is no specific support within the framework for what you want to achieve. The answer to this previous question (stackoverflow.com/questions/8618157/…) using metaclasses may allow you to do what you want without having to update each and every one of your tests

Answer (score 2):

[TemplateMethod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) pattern to the rescue:

```
class BaseTest(unitest.Testcase):
    def validate(self):
       do_the_common_validation()
       self.validate_more()

    def validate_more(self):
        pass
```

Then in your subclasses you just have to override `validate_more()`.

Comment: I am aware of this approach, however my question explicitly was asking about a way to do that "without having to modify all testcases", and obviously this approach will require me to rename the validate action to validate_more in all testcases. 
Thanks anyway for your note that however doesn't answer my question